# Flutter: Reading step counter data from Android API without needing to move the phone

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to read the pedometer API's step counter data ([developer.android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor#TYPE_STEP_COUNTER)) to see how many steps the user has when they launch the app.

I am using [Pedometer Package](https://pub.dev/packages/pedometer) to read the data.

However, I notice that I'm able to see the steps just fine if the phone is moving when I'm reading the data. If the phone is stationary however (like on a table), it will never read the data, until I move my phone a bit.

I would really like this to work so that I don't need to do any prompt like "shake your phone" to read the steps. There must be a way to do this, right?

The function I hate to read the steps is:

```
Future<void> gameInitLoadStepCount(WidgetRef ref) async {
  var stepCounterWorks = true;
  final stepCountStream = Pedometer.stepCountStream;
  final stepCountSubscription = stepCountStream.listen(null);
  stepCountSubscription.onError((error) async {
    await changeLoadingText('Step counter failure.', ref);
    stepCounterWorks = false;
  });
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
  // If the step counter works, load the steps
  if (stepCounterWorks) {
    // Load the first step event
    final lastEvent = await stepCountStream.first;
    await changeLoadingText('Steps loaded: ${lastEvent.steps}', ref);
  }
}
```

Please, if anyone know a solution to make this work that would save my day!